# Problema ao recarregar página que possui parâmetro no Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

As vezes é necessário enviar um parâmetro através de uma rota

No meu caso está acontecendo assim:

Quando minha rota (URL) não tem parâmetro, posso pressionar a tecla F5 e a página carrega normalmente.

Porém quando a rota tem algum parâmetro `localhost:8080/path/1`, após carregar e caso haja a necessidade de pressionar a tecla F5

Tenho esses erros:

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/editar/vendors.fdbbeba1.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
11:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/editar/main.50725ff9.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
5
```

A configuração da minha rota está assim:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/editar/:id',
        name: 'editar',
        component: () => import('../views/Edit.vue')
    },
    
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
    routes
})

export default router
```

Como sou novo no Vue gostaria de perguntar: É normal no Vue ou tenho que fazer alguma configuração adicional?

Comment: Tens algum ficheiro vue.config.js? Parece-me que ele está a procura desses recursos no diretório errado.

Comment: Estou usando o webpack. Mas quando chamo a primeira vez a página, carrega, mas quando atualizo, que dá esse problema